# SQL Phone number Transulation from xxx-xxx-xxxx to (xxx) xxx-xxx

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to format a phone number from a select statement in `SQL Server`.  The format in the DB is `XXX-XXX-XXXX`.

I need to show on a text file as (xxx) xxx-xxxx

Can anyone help me with this?

```
convert(char(14),REPLACE(person.phone, '-', '')), --Person Phone
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string manipulation:

```
select '(' + stuff(phone, 4, 1, ') ')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=031baf6d98c29c2d1f9e129a8b5e0d56) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
declare @test varchar(max);

set @test = '123-456-7890'

select '(' + substring (@test, 0, len(@test)-8) + ')' + substring (@test, 5, len(@test)-1)
```

To do it from table

```
select '(' + substring (fieldName, 0, len(fieldName)-8) + ')' + substring (fieldName, 5, len(fieldName)-1) 
from tableName
```

Comment: why is there a negative mark to this answer that works fine for me?

Comment: I saw that. Someone marked negative shortly after the post went up.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: thanks @dizzle . Please accept the answer that was helpful to you.